# Number of Salesforce certified experts

Tags: certification, certificates

Lately I have seen for example new Application Architect certifications with certification number code like 0000700. Does that mean, that there is 700 certified persons? This numbering does not make sense with other certificates, where the number is above tens of millions (like Data architect and managment designer).

Answer (score 3):

It is because [Application Architect is earned upon completion of other certifications](http://www.salesforce.com/assets/pdf/misc/salesforce-architect-journey.pdf):

> **Salesforce Certified Application Architect** *For those who assess
>   functional requirements from a declarative viewpoint.*
>
> - Certified Data Architecture and Management Designer
> - Certified Sharing and Visibility Designer
> - Certified Platform Developer I
> - Certified Platform App Builder
> - Certified Community Cloud Consultant* (Optional)

[image]
***Disclaimer:*** Salesforce certification types, requirements, and structure is changed often. I'm not really following it, and can't tell whether the document I'm referencing is current, but it is a great illustration that helps visualize certifications relationships.

**UPDATE: [An Ultimate Guide of Certification Paths](https://secure2.sfdcstatic.com/assets/pdf/misc/sfu-certification-guide-summer-16.pdf)**

Comment: This is current and it was just released at Dreamforce this year but it only refers to the new path to Technical Architect, ignoring administrator and "implementation expert" certifications

Comment: @brezotom see my update

Comment: @Oleksiy i was only curious about numbering, or how to get the real number of existing certificates. But thanks anyway ;)

Comment: @Martin.Kona Even knowing the last issued certificate number, you won't know how many are valid, unless Salesforce is disclosing this information